# How to sort a large file >10Gb consisting of words?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I have been given this interview question:

> Given an input file with **words** (may be a random set of letters) separated by commas, the file weighs **10 GB** (or more).
> Provide an algorithm to **sort** all these words.
> Assume you have **1 GB** RAM.
> All this needs to be done natively using NodeJS.

### My analysis:

1. First of all, we need to read the file given to us;
   `const readStream = fs.createReadStream('randomWords.csv', { highWaterMark: CHUNK_SIZE });`
2. Split it into sorted chunks
   (words can be truncated, the truncated word is transferred to the next chunk file);
3. The name of each chunk file will be its first word. Exp.:

   > Some chunk file: `aaeknocvxg, aaocurnro, aaoudf, ..., zzqooe, zzwm`.
   > It turns out that the **name** will be aaeknocvxg_0.csv.

   ***..._0*** - chunk index (to avoid collisions)
4. We read the entire list of chunk file names, sort them, write the first word of the array into the final file.
5. We rename the chunk file that was found to the next word from its file, we also delete the word from the file. Repeat the process until all files are empty.
6. The resulting file is sorted!

### Implementation:

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME = './chunks/';

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('randomWords.csv', { highWaterMark: 64 * 1024 });

const customSort = () => {
  let unprocesed = '';
  let chunkName = '';
  let i = 0;

  readStream.on('data', chunk => {
    const chunkString = unprocesed + chunk.toString();
    unprocesed = '';

    const chunkArray = chunkString.split(', ');
    unprocesed = chunkArray.pop();
    const sortedChunkArray = chunkArray.sort();

    chunkName = `${CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME}${sortedChunkArray[0]}_${++i}.csv`;

    fs.writeFileSync(chunkName, sortedChunkArray.join(', '));
  });

  readStream.on('end', () => {
    if (unprocesed) {
      let lastChunk = fs.readFileSync(chunkName);

      const chunkString = lastChunk.toString();

      const chunkArray = chunkString.split(', ');
      chunkArray.push(unprocesed);

      const sortedChunkArray = chunkArray.sort();

      fs.unlinkSync(chunkName);

      fs.writeFileSync(
        `${CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME}${sortedChunkArray[0]}_${i}.csv`,
        sortedChunkArray.join(', '),
      );
    }

    let hasFiles = true;

    while (hasFiles) {
      let fileNameList = [];

      fs.readdirSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME).forEach(file => {
        fileNameList.push(file);
      });

      if (fileNameList.length === 0) {
        hasFiles = false;
        break;
      }

      let smallestName = fileNameList.sort()[0];

      const [word, extension] = smallestName.split('_');

      fs.appendFileSync('sortedWords.csv', `${word}, `);

      let smallestData = fs.readFileSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + smallestName);

      fs.unlinkSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + smallestName);

      const smallestString = smallestData.toString();

      if (smallestString) {
        const smallestArray = smallestString.split(', ');

        const slicedSmallestArray = smallestArray.slice(1);

        if (slicedSmallestArray.length !== 0) {
          fs.writeFileSync(
            `${CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME}${slicedSmallestArray[0]}_${extension}`,
            slicedSmallestArray.join(', '),
          );
        }
      }
    }
  });
};

exports.customSort = customSort;
```

### Question:

The algorithm is obviously not good, how would you do it using **merge sort**?

Comment: (Half a point for originality.)

Comment: I really want to understand how to solve the task correctly. ty

Comment: The chunks approach is correct, I'd use a merge-sort approach on disk. I advise you to ask your question on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: PS. I hadn't noticed you had already mentioned merge sort in your question, sorry for being redundant

Comment: Can't we use Radix sort? Radix sort does not require comparisons, just placing items in buckets. Buckets can be files, which lets us get around the memory constraint.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Interesting, I think I'll give it a try. Thanks, but still, is it possible to use merge sort?

Comment: @גלעדברקן - using files for buckets would involve a lot of random access, an issue if the files are on hard drives. Radix sort could be used for chunks of memory for the initial pass that creates the sorted sub-files.

Answer (score 2):

A simple merge/(divide & conquer) sort solution would be:

1. Sort smaller batches (i.e. 300MB or even 1GB) in internal memory with the algorithm of your choice and save them in a file (sorted batch).
2. Merge two sorted batches into a larger one by splitting the RAM into *3* (*output, batch1, batch2*). If the *output* file is full, write to the external file, in case one of the *batches* is empty, read more from the corresponding external-batch file. Continue with 2. until there is only one single sorted file.

Comment: `splitting the RAM into 3` - How to do it? Where can you read about it?

Comment: or less, just that 3 equally large arrays (or other data-structures) fit into the internal memory, in the case above 1GB / 3. 
The I/O operation (which you want to minimize) can read and write probably anyways much less then 300MB, called [B size of the block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_memory_algorithm#Algorithms) you can read or write.

Comment: There is also a more refined merge sort with less I/O operations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-way_merge_algorithm#External_sorting

Comment: Thanks for the information provided, I'll check it out.

Comment: you are welcome, external memory algorithms is quit a big theoretic research area too.

Comment: Could you please help me understand how the merge, which is writing to the final file, takes into account large differences in chunk ranges? For example, if we have chunks {1,2,3,4,5,6} and {10,11,12,13,14,15}, and our batch size is 3. Wouldn't the final file result in [1,2,3,10,11,12], then on the second batch run we'd add [4,5,6,13,14,16], and the final file would not be sorted? I don't understand how a correct final file could be created from a merge.

Comment: The merging step is like a sorted zip.
In external mem: you have your two sorted chunk1, chunk2. 
For Internal mem: (lets say can only hold 9 items in RAM = [[sorted_intern][chunk1_intern][chunk2_intern]]) and batch size for I/O is 3. Read the first 3 items each to chunk*_intern. 
[sorted_intern] will soon be [1,2,3] and full, thus written to the merge file, then the first chunk is empty and we read the next three items [4,5,6] and continue the zip. 
To sort you example it takes 4 reads and 4 writes to external memory.

Comment: Ah, thanks! My mistake was imagining the out twice the size.

Answer (score 1):

First split the files to 26 files or less, each for first letter. Then assumingly they will be less than 1GB, sort them each. Then combine. for brevity we assume lower case letters.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME = './chunks/';
const options = { highWaterMark: 10 }       // or any size
const readStream = fs.createReadStream('randomWords.csv', options);
const alpha = Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65);
const alphabet = alpha.map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x).toLowerCase());

const customSort = () => {

    prepare();

    let last = '';

    readStream.on('data', chunk => {
        const chunkString = last + chunk.toString();
        const chunkArray = chunkString.split(',');
        last = chunkArray.pop();
        chunkArray.forEach(function (word) {
            word = word.trim();
            var letter = word.substring(0, 1);
            fs.appendFileSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter + "/letter-" + letter + ".csv", word + ",");
        })
    });

    readStream.on('end', () => {
        if (last) {
            var word = last;
            word = word.trim();         
            var letter = last.trim().substring(0, 1);
            fs.appendFileSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter + "/letter-" + letter + ".csv", word + ",");
        }

        // now sort every letter file (for clarity we sort it with \n as separator)
        alphabet.forEach(function (letter) {
            if (fs.existsSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter + "/letter-" + letter + '.csv')) {
                var content = fs.readFileSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter + "/letter-" + letter + '.csv');
                content = content.toString().split(",").sort().join("\n").trim() + (letter != 'z' ? "\n" : "")
                fs.appendFileSync("./final-sorted.txt", content);
            }
        })

        console.log("done")
    });
};


function prepare() {
    // create empty a,b,c folders
    alphabet.forEach(function (letter) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter)
        }
        if (fs.existsSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter + "/letter-" + letter + '.csv')) {
            fs.unlinkSync(CHUNK_FOLDER_NAME + letter + "/letter-" + letter + '.csv');
        }
    })
    if (fs.existsSync("./final-sorted.txt")) {
        fs.unlinkSync("./final-sorted.txt");
    }
}

customSort();
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you can do `content.toString().split(",").sort().join("\n").trim()` with the memory constraint imposed?

Comment: Yes because it's likely to be size of (10/26)GB. You can optimize the solution to include more letters :-)

Comment: It's a great idea to break all chunks alphabetically. I think to add not 26, but from two letters i.e. 26 * 26 so that the file is not limited to 26gb. WDT?

Comment: @AKX The content object will not exceed 1GB of memory, so there should be no problems.

Comment: _"Then assumingly they will be less than 1GB"_. Why? The file could contain "aaaaaa" trillions of times for all we know

Comment: @ITgoldman But what if it suddenly turns out that in a large file all words begin with the same letter?

Comment: And what if there's a 2GB long word? That's not the point of the question. But indeed this solution can be improved and you raised a valid caveats.

Comment: Writing to 26 files at the same time is going to involve a lot of random access, which would be an issue if a hard drive is used instead of a solid state drive.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudocode for an approach I've used for a harder variation of this problem in real life.

First create a `wordBuffer` class which supports the following API:

```
// Construct it.
wb = new WordBuffer()
// Tell it to be backed by a file, instead of an array.
// If the file is nonempty, it will assume finished writing and that
// the size is the size of the file.
wb.setFileName(file)
// Add a word.  Can only call if haven't finished writing.
wb.add(word)
// Mark done writing.
wb.finishWriting()
// How much is in it?
wb.size
// What file is it backed by?  May be undefined.
wb.filename
// Gets the next word and advances.  May give undefined.
wb.getWord()
```

With these we can easily define a merge function as follows.

```
function merge (in1, in2) {
    let out = new WordBuffer();
    if (in1.size + in2.size > 10000000) {
        wb.setFileName(`buffer/${counter}.buf`);
        counter++;
    }
    let word1 = in1.getWord();
    let word2 = in2.getWord();
    while ((word1 != undefined) && (word2 != undefined)) {
        if (word1 < word2) {
            out.add(word1);
            word1 = in1.getWord();
        }
        else {
            out.add(word2);
            word2 = in2.getWord();
        }
    }
    while (word1 != undefined) {
        out.add(word1);
        word1 = in1.getWord();
    }
    while (word2 != undefined) {
        out.add(word2);
        word1 = in2.getWord();
    }
    out.finishWriting();
    return out;
}
```

And now for the cascading merge logic.

```
let chunks = [];
let inWB = new WordBuffer();
inWB.setFileName(inputFile);
let word = inWB.getWord();
while (word != undefined) {
    tmpWB = new WordBuffer();
    tmpWB.add(word);
    tmpWB.finishWriting();
    chunks.push(tmpWB);
    while ((1 < chunks.length) && (chunks[-2].size * 0.8 < chunks[-1].size)) {
        chunks.push(merge(chunks.pop(), chunks.pop()));
    }
}
while (1 < chunks.length) {
    chunks.push(merge(chunks.pop(), chunks.pop()));
}

// And now we can copy from chunks[0] - either read and write,
// or just move the underlying file to where we want the sorted output.
```

Note that when I solved this, I found that keeping the temporary files compressed was worth it.  The CPU overhead was less than I gained in file I/O.  That was some years ago though, so YMMV.  I also didn't write this to be async, that would take some thought.  And finally, replacing the first few levels of mergesort with the built in library sort would probably be a significant performance boost.  (It was for me.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 10 chunks of 1GB each. Sort each chunk individually using merge sort (or any other algorithm for that matter).
2. Create a pointer to each chunk, to have a total of 10 pointers. Create a pointer which points to the output file.
3. Pick the pointer that points towards the minimum value/character/string. Write that value to the output pointer, and increment the source pointer.
4. Continue this process till all characters/chunks aren't covered.

This won't exceed the memory limit at any point, since the maximum data that we'll store in the memory at a single point of time will be the chunk size, which is equal to 1GB in this case.

Comment: I do exactly that, simplifying the task by the fact that the pointer is the name of the chunk file.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `split` portion of the `external merge sort` looks fine. The `merge` portion it's just merging the files based on the file name which in this case first word of the file and not based on the words inside.
I've created a library called `large-sort` that can definitely help.

`large-sort` is definitely the fastest pure node external merge sort library I've seen so far.

NPM Package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/large-sort

Here is the repo:
https://github.com/nelson-perez/large-sort

Here is an example of how you would sort words separated by commas.

```js
import 'large-sort';

// Function that transforms a word to a string (no-op)
const inputMapFunction = (input: string) => input;

// Function that transforms word to word string. (no-op)
const outputMapFuncton = (output: string) => output;

// Function that compares two words to define their sort order.
let compareFunction = (a: number, b: number) => a > b? 1 : -1;

 // Sorts the lines of the file "input_file.txt" as numbers and outputs it to the "out_sorted_file.txt" file
 await sortFile<number>(
    'input_file.txt',
    'output_sorted_file.txt',
    inputMapFunction,
    outputMapFuncton,
    compareFunction,
    ', ' // input delimiter
    ', ' // output delimiter
);
```